# Where is the "int main" Function in the Dev C++ Windows Template?

Tags: c++, user-interface, program-entry-point, dev-c++

I a making a GUI project and I when I start up, I want two windows:

one main window, and the other a SYSMENU window on top to create a new project etc. I am using the template and I want to remove the main function from both classes and put it in a different init.cpp class. How?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply put, you can't do that in a way you think.

Comment: uh... can it be done? sorry im new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev C++ is an old IDE that's no longer much used.

If it has a template for a Windows API level GUI program, then that template most likely has a Microsoft-specific `WinMain` function instead of a standard C++ `main` function.

With the default toolchain for Dev C++, namely GNU (g++ and its linker), you can just remove the Microsoft-specific `WinMain` and use a standard `main` instead.

Note that with Microsoft's toolchain you will then have to explicitly instruct the linker to accept a standard `main`.

But, take one step at a time.

Comment: Old? may be. But it has recent updates: [http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/] and [http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.it/2013/02/dev-c-540-released.html]

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, I get one page not found and one bad request, by the way.

Comment: Now i get it this way http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.it (looks like intenal URL are dynamic ...)